# nsis function Skip Page

Tags: nsis

I want to create a custom silent mode which display only the license.
For exemple, I have tested this :

`!define` MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE skipPage

`!insertmacro` MUI_PAGE_WELCOME

Function skipPage

```
${GetOptions} $CMDLINE "--quiet" $0
${If} $0 == "--quiet"
    Abort
${EndIf}
```

FunctionEnd

But the page is not skipped, an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with skipping pages, you are simply using `${GetOptions}` incorrectly.

The returned variable contains the data **after** the switch itself. If you just want to detect the switch you should check for errors:

```
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
Function skipPage
${GetParameters} $R0
ClearErrors
${GetOptions} $R0 "--quiet" $0
${IfNot} ${Errors}
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: It works, but MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES is also skipped, I just wanted to hide it. `HideWindow ` should work but there is no text in the Reference/HideWindow page.

Comment: `HideWindow` doesn't need args. My English is bad so I sometimes don't understand the nsis docs.